# VB.net - Adding a row to datagridview returns InvalidArgument=Value '8797' is invalid for 'rowIndex'

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, row

I have been scratching my head for a while to try and find a solution, I haven't been able to find anything related when searching on Google, so after many hours of trying to find the cause behind this problem, I am trying to ask for help here..

The weird thing is that the error doesn't happen right away, but at random times typically after a few thousand rows have been checked.

The application itself is a link extractor, which extracts links from different URIs, and then when it finds new internal links, it adds them to the datagridview.

When I look at some of IntelliTrace exceptions, it says the error is thrown at this line:
[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOlLZ.png)

Or in code..

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(matchUrl), anchor_txt, "", "", "", True})
```

It doesn't really make sense to me why it throws such a high index integer though, and especially not at this line, when all it does is add a new row.. Anyway, the index have probably existed at one point, but for each scan, I remove the URIs that does not contain x string, and then I scan for links again, until there are none left.

Here's a stacktrace if it can be at any help:

```
System.ArgumentException: InvalidArgument=Værdi '8797' er ugyldig for 'rowIndex'.
ved System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.GetState(Int32 rowIndex)
ved System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.GetRowState(Int32 rowIndex)
ved System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.UpdateRowCaches(Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewRow& dataGridViewRow, Boolean adding)
ved System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.OnCollectionChanged_PreNotification(CollectionChangeAction cca, Int32 rowIndex, Int32 rowCount, DataGridViewRow& dataGridViewRow, Boolean changeIsInsertion)
ved System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.OnCollectionChanged(CollectionChangeEventArgs e, Int32 rowIndex, Int32 rowCount)
ved System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.AddInternal(Boolean newRow, Object[] values)
ved System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.Add(Object[] values)
ved Link_Extractor.Form1.InternalThread2() i C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Link\Link\Form1.vb:linje 568
```

I also receive a "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object" or NullReferenceException at "For each" line. I guess this might be if the cell(0) is for some reason null - I will check for this now, but still doesn't explain the first one.

```
For Each itm As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If itm.Cells(0).Value = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(matchUrl) Then
           exists = True
    End If
Next
```

Where this is the stacktrace:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Objektreferencen er ikke indstillet til en forekomst af et objekt.
ved System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.OnCollectionChanged(CollectionChangeEventArgs e, Int32 rowIndex, Int32 rowCount)
ved System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.AddInternal(Boolean newRow, Object[] values)
ved System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.Add(Object[] values)
ved Link_Extractor.Form1.InternalThread3() i C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Link\Link\Form1.vb:linje 808
```

**EDIT**
Here's some more code, after it receives the html page.

```
If Not data = "" Then

                    Dim links As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(data, "<a.*?href=[""']?([^'"">\ ]*)[""']?[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/a>")

                    For Each match As Match In links

                        Dim matchUrl As String = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(match.Groups(1).Value)
                        Dim anchor As String = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(StripTags(match.Groups(2).Value))

                        'Ignore all anchor links
                        If matchUrl.StartsWith("#") Then
                            Continue For
                        End If
                        'Ignore all javascript calls
                        If matchUrl.ToLower.StartsWith("javascript:") Then
                            Continue For
                        End If
                        'Ignore all email links
                        If matchUrl.ToLower.StartsWith("mailto:") Then
                            Continue For
                        End If
                        'Ignore all URLs with @
                        If matchUrl.ToLower.Contains("@") Then
                            Continue For
                        End If
                        'Ignore all empty domains
                        If matchUrl Is Nothing Then
                            Throw New Exception("Empty matchurl")
                        End If
                        If anchor Is Nothing Then
                            Throw New Exception("Empty anchor text.")
                        End If
                        'For internal links, build the url mapped to the base address

                        If Not matchUrl.StartsWith("http://") And Not matchUrl.StartsWith("https://") Then

                            'Højst sansynligt internt link
                            matchUrl = MapUrl(url, matchUrl)
                            Try
                                exists = False
                                For Each itm As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                                    If Not itm.Cells(0) Is Nothing Then
                                        If itm.Cells(0).Value = matchUrl Then
                                            exists = True
                                            Exit For
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Next
                                If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso exists = True Then
                                    Continue For
                                Else
                                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {matchUrl, anchor, "", "", "", True})
                                End If
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                            End Try

                        Else

                            'It's possible that it still can be an internal link, but also external. Compare the baseaddress with the URL to check if it's still the same domain

                            Dim baseaddress As Uri = New Uri(url)
                            Dim s_baseaddress As String = baseaddress.Host.ToString
                            'Check for subdomain and remove
                            If s_baseaddress.ToCharArray().Count(Function(c) c = "."c) >= 2 Then
                                Dim subdomain As String = Split(s_baseaddress, ".").First
                                s_baseaddress = s_baseaddress.Replace(subdomain & ".", "")
                            End If

                            Dim s_url As String = Nothing
                            Dim url2 As Uri = Nothing
                            Try
                                url2 = New Uri(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(matchUrl))
                                s_url = url2.Host.ToString
                                If s_url.ToCharArray().Count(Function(c) c = "."c) >= 2 Then
                                    Dim subdomain As String = Split(s_url, ".").First
                                    s_url = s_url.Replace(subdomain & ".", "")
                                End If
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                'Invalid URI
                                Continue For
                            End Try

                            If s_baseaddress.Equals(s_url) Then

                                'Internal

                                Try

                                    exists = False
                                    For Each itm As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                                        If Not itm.Cells(0) Is Nothing Then
                                            If itm.Cells(0).Value = matchUrl Then
                                                exists = True
                                                Exit For
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    Next
                                    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso exists = True Then
                                        Continue For
                                    Else
                                        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {matchUrl, anchor, "", "", "", True})
                                    End If

                                Catch ex As Exception
                                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                                End Try

                            Else

                                'External link
                                Dim m_url As String = matchUrl
                                m_url = m_url.Replace(" ", "")

                                'Trim url to root to save the time of removing duplicates
                                Dim theUri = Nothing
                                Try
                                    theUri = New Uri(m_url)
                                Catch ex As Exception
                                    'Invalid link, go to next
                                    Continue For
                                End Try
                                Dim theDomain = theUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)

                                Try

                                    exists = False
                                    For Each itm As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
                                        If Not itm.Cells(0) Is Nothing Then
                                            If itm.Cells(0).Value = theDomain.ToString Then
                                                exists = True
                                                Exit For
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    Next
                                    If DataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso exists = True Then
                                        Continue For
                                    Else
                                        DataGridView2.Rows.Add(New String() {theDomain.ToString, anchor, ""})
                                        e_links_c += 1
                                    End If

                                Catch ex As Exception
                                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                                End Try

                            End If

                        End If

                    Next

                    'OK
                    DataGridView1.Rows(thi3).Cells(2).Value = "OK"
                    DataGridView1.Rows(thi3).Cells(3).Value = e_links_c.ToString

                Else
                    'Error
                    DataGridView1.Rows(thi3).Cells(2).Value = "Empty response"

                End If
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(matchUrl)` gives you invalid data. Since your code snippet has `Continue For`, my assumption is you have 2 `For` loops.

1. Are you sure `matchUrl` has valid value ?
2. Validate the `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(matchUrl)` value before adding to Rows and before using it in If condition. Though you validate the `anchor_txt`.
3. Code snippet does not show `Try` and `Catch` block. If you are not using it, please do so.
4. Use `Exit For` in the inner `For` loop, after `exists = True` statement.
5. Code evaluates `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(matchUrl)` at two different instances and it is evaluated multiple times in the inner `For` loop. Assign its value to a variable before the For loop. Validate the output and then use this value in `For` loop.

Try below code:-

```
Try
    exists = False
    urlDecode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(matchUrl)  'Put a break point on this statement and check the value of matchUrl and HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(matchUrl)
    If urlDecode is Nothing Then  
        Throw New Exception("Empty urlDecode.")
    End If
    For Each itm As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If itm.Cells(0).Value = urlDecode Then
               exists = True
               Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso exists then
        Continue For
    Else
        Dim anchor_txt As String = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(StrpTags(match.Groups(2).Value))
        If urlDecode is Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception("Empty anchor text.")
        End If
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(matchUrl), anchor_txt, "", "", "", True})
    End If      
Catch ex As Exception
        ' Show the exception's message.
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: I am positive that matchurl returns a positive value. And yes, I do have 2 for each loops, the main one is where it checks all the links of the html page, and the 2nd it checks for duplicates in the datagridview. I do actually check if matchurl is nothing further up the code. I have added Try catch again, and I have added Exit for when it finds duplicate + defined string so it doesnt call to httputility htmldecode multiple times.

Comment: I have just run the application again with the changes, but it still returned the two errors. I have added more code above so you can get a better understanding of the code.

Comment: @JDoe, did u try putting a break point at `urlDecode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(matchUrl)`. What is the value of urlDecode ? Is it correct and as expected ?

Comment: Typo corrected in the code above. `If urlDecoded is Nothing Then` updated to `If urlDecode is Nothing Then`. Used notepad for code editing. So please excuse me for typos.

Comment: I just had a successful run on the same scrape that returned errors before. I now declare the matchurl and anchor at the top. I will try to run another scrape and see if that returns any errors, as I am not 100% sure if its resolved. The value of matchurl appears to be correct and not null, when it returned errors previously, I also looked at this. I did notice that there were some duplicates in my datagridviews now though, so I will have to look into that too.

Comment: I ended up adding delegates where it checks for duplicates within, and also add the rows from there, haven't seen any of the previous errors yet, so it appears that solved it. Thank you for your assistance!